# how to update a portion of existing excel sheet with filtered dataframe?

Tags: excel, pandas, pandas.excelwriter

I have an excel workbook with several sheets. I need to read a portion from one of the sheets, get a filtered dataframe and write a single value from that filtered dataframe to a specific cell in the same sheet. What is the best way to accomplish this, ideally without opening the excel workbook? I need to run this on linux, so can't use xlwings. I don't want to write the entire sheet, but just a selected cell/offset inside it. I tried the following to write to the existing sheet, but doesn't seem to work for me (no update occurs at the desired cell):

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') as writer:
    writer.book = load_workbook('test.xlsx')
    df_filtered.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet_Name', columns=['CS'], startrow=638, startcol=96)
```

Any tips would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just writing a single cell the below should suffice.

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[1,2,3], columns=['col'])
filtered_dataframe = df[df.col == 1].values[0][0]

filename = 'test.xlsx'
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
wb['Sheet1'].cell(column=1, row=2, value=filtered_dataframe)
wb.save(filename)
```

I believe your issue was that you never called the save method of the writer.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! The only other issue I am having is that the Excel workbook needs to be closed before wb.save(filename) is executed - is that expected behavior? Can the update occur while leaving excel open?

Comment: openpyxl works by directly editing the file on disk so the workbook you've loaded into ram will not be affected. If you want to edit the spreadsheet with excel open - look into xlwings - it uses excel directly.

Comment: I have used xlwings and it does work with excel open, however, xlwings has a windows dependency and doesn't work on linux unless I am missing something.

Comment: That's correct, I don't believe there is an obvious way to update an open spreadsheet on linux.